# How do I activate the network beacon(s) in the Sonoran Desert?

Tags: global-agenda

There are network beacons in the Sonoran Desert similar to the beacons in the PvP and PvE missions. It looks like they might be available in various areas of the desert - though I am not sure how to activate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've done the right missions, you'll be able to use them (U), a map will come up and you'll be able to click on one of the other beacons on the map that you have already activated, or the default ones nearer the dome if it's your first beacon.